# How to describe 'Mutual Benefits' in academic terms in the following?

Tags: writing-style, academia, writing-advice

I am writing a proposal for a joint collaboration with a University in Singapore. I aim to use their facilities to gain hands-on experience. 
In the following, the excerpt from my proposal is presented. First thing is, how should I coin the term 'mutual benefit' that it looks academically sound and also gives the impression that there is an actual gain for them as well in this?

*Note that I actually mean every word I have written in the following and do not just want to get into their research facility.*

> **Mutual Benefits:** It is expected that this project will contribute
>   towards adding new functionalities to the XYZ testbed, while giving
>   us the opportunity to practically investigate the discovery mechanism
>   for mobile vehicles. The results obtained through this project will be
>   published in good quality peer-reviewed journals or conferences.
>   Depending on the quality of the results, future collaboration and
>   funding options will also be explored.

Comment: The expression is "mutual benefit," as in, "It will be to our mutual benefit."  Notice that "benefit" isn't plural.  That's because the expression is treated like a noncount noun.  Therefore, in that heading, you should change "**Mutual Benefits**" to "**Mutual Benefit**."

Comment: @Billy Thanks. On a second thought, can I use "Collaborative Benefit" or "Collaborative Gain"?

Comment: Writing advice may be OT.

Comment: @Sjaffry -- That's fine, but in business communication, which is what a proposal like this is, even if it is going to a university, there's an old adage: "Never use a $5 word where a 50¢ word will do."  That seems like what you're doing -- using a $5 word where a 50¢ word will do.